# Use of IndySleep on IdTCPServer1Execute

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

It's recommended add a IndySleep(Value) on IdTCPServer1Execute event?
if yes, what value you recommend use?

I ask it because my IdTCPServer are using so much CPU when many clients are connected.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the CPU load high even if the clients are idle? In this case, there might be inefficient code in the IdTCPServer1Execute event handler.

Comment: High CPU load typically means you have runaway threads, or are performing a lot of unyielding operations. Consider fixing the root issue instead of patching it with a sleep bandaid

Comment: Client side send a ping to server every 1/2 second. i already use a queue to fire any command to client.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended add a IndySleep(Value) on IdTCPServer1Execute event? Yes

If yes, what value you recommend use? 1000/(number of clients)

Comment: So you recommend use IndySleep(1000 div IdTCPServer1.Contexts.Count) at the end of OnExecute event?

Comment: Yes, it is. If not used, the CPU usage will increase significantly.